# NLog - How do I get caller class name and method programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I'm using this [https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/master/examples/ExtendingLoggers/LoggerWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/master/examples/ExtendingLoggers/LoggerWrapper%20%22NLog%20extending%20loggers%20-%20LoggerWrapper) method of extending NLog so that I can add custom properties to my events.  So my code looks like this:

```
    public void WriteMessage(string eventID, string message)
    {
        LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, _logger.Name, message);

        logEvent.Properties["EventID"] = eventID;

        _logger.Log(typeof(MyLogger), logEvent);
    }
```

Within the `WriteMessage` method I tried to get the caller class and method names as follows:

```
logEvent.CallerClassName;
logEvent.CallerMemberName;
```

but both return null.

How can I get the values?

Answer (score 5):

Just like you can assign `LogEventInfo.Exception` then you can also assign `LogEventInfo.CallerClassName` (or `LogEventInfo.CallerMemberName`).

Calling the getter for `LogEventInfo.Exception` will only return an Exception-object if one assigned. The same goes for `LogEventInfo.CallerClassName` (or `LogEventInfo.CallerMemberName`)

The NLog `Logger` is responsible for doing capture of callsite. The `Logger` performs the capture when receiving the `LogEventInfo`. The capture is very expensive and only occurs if a target has been configured to use callsite.

Instead of trying to walk the StackTrace yourself. Then you might want to make use of caller-information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information

NLog v5 introduces a new [fluent-Logger-API](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Logger-API), that captures source-file + line-number + class-name with minimal overhead for use with [${callsite:captureStackTrace=false}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer):

```cs
_logger.ForInfoEvent()
       .Message("This is a fluent message {0}", "test")
       .Property("PropertyName", "PropertyValue")
       .Log();
```

Comment: Rolf are you saying that I need to manually grab caller info and pass it into my WriteMessage method, and that I can’t grab it from NLog? Also is it too late to get it once I’m already inside writemessage since then I’ll have WriteMessage as the caller and not the original location?

Comment: I am saying that if you need the callsite somewhere in your NLog target, and you don't want to capture it yourself. Then just use `${callsite}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer

Comment: Ok so In my code sample above when I reference `${callsite}` in my layout it’s too late since callsite says I’m in `WriteMessage`.  So in that case I have no choice but to grab caller info myself (however I cam get it) - outside of nlog - and pass it into `WriteMessage`, correct?

Comment: @Howiecamp When calling `_logger.Log(typeof(MyLogger), logEvent);` make sure that the `typeof` is specifying the class-type that contains the method `WriteMessage`. NLog will ignore all methods from the class (or interface) specified in the `typeof` (Make sure to use NLog 4.5 or newer). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Custom-extension-of-Logger-interface#custom-wrapper-and-callsite

Comment: When my messages appear in my log files they definitely have the correct target info - no problem there.  What I'm trying to do though is get that callsite information separately, inside the WriteMessage method, so I can use it in other ways.  E.g. I am creating elasticsearch documents from the log info and I want to have a field speciifcally for the caller info.  Today, just like in the log files, the caller (callsite) shows up as part of the entire log record, but I want to grab the caller info separately, programmatically.  Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Lets say you are using `NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch` then you can see in the wiki to add your own custom fields: https://github.com/reactive-markets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki (There you can specify `field name="callsite" layout="${callsite}"`)